# Fixed Width Multiple Violin Plots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I have multiple violin plots, each plot with a variable number of violins (samples). I'm wondering if there is a way to make each violin's plotting width to be the same, so that regardless of how many violins are within each plot and how many plots there are, they will all have the same plotting width.

EDIT 1: Adding example code. I am thinking of a situation like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$carb <= 3,], aes(carb, mpg, group = carb)) +
    geom_violin()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$carb > 3,], aes(carb, mpg, group = carb)) +
    geom_violin()
```

[image]

There are two different plots with differing numbers of violins in each. I would like to make the width of the violins in each plot the same.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of violins you'd ever show? If not, I'm not sure how this is solvable. That max number is what you'd have to size everything to.

Answer (score 1):

From `?geom_violin`:

> scale
>
> if "area" (default), all violins have the same area (before
> trimming the tails). If "count", areas are scaled proportionally to
> the number of observations. If "width", all violins have the same
> maximum width.

Compare:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, mpg, group = carb)) +
  geom_violin()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, mpg, group = carb)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "width")
```

[image]

In `mtcars`, the carb groups have different numbers of samples.

```
dplyr::count(mtcars, carb)

  carb  n
1    1  7
2    2 10
3    3  3
4    4 10
5    6  1
6    8  1
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I have in mind. Imagine an additional violin plot with 2 samples (2 violins), below the one you have. I want all the samples to have the same width.

Comment: Please explain more. You said you want each violin's plotting width to be the same regardless of the number of samples. The carb=3 violin has 3 samples and the carb=4 has 10, but they are the same width. How is that different from what you're looking for?

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 in the original post.